# Openlayers inherits method undefined in custom control loaded via shimming in webpack

Tags: openlayers-3, webpack-2, es6-shim

I try to include the [LayerSwitcher Custom Control](https://github.com/Viglino/ol3-ext) with webpack in my project, but I always receive the error that `ol.inhereits`is undefined in this line:

```
ol.inherits(ol.control.LayerSwitcher, ol.control.Control);
```

https://github.com/Viglino/ol3-ext/blob/ddc2f631348f8b1cfb5d24e8cf83ed13c262411d/dist/ol3-ext.js#L94

I already debugged this in firefox 57 (See screenshot) and I don't know why the method is not found, although the module is initialized/imported.
  Is there missing something?

[image]

My webpack config is the following:

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'IndexJS'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        ],
        rules: [
        {
                test: require.resolve("./ol3-ext-1.0.1/dist/ol3-ext.js"),
                loader: "imports-loader?$=jquery,ol=ol,ol.control=ol/control"
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve("./ol3-ext-1.0.1/dist/ol3-ext.js"),
                loader: "exports-loader?LayerSwitcher=LayerSwitcher,LayerPopup=LayerPopup"
            }

        ]
```

Comment: Maybe the `ol.control` assignment overwrites the `ol` assignment? Try to change the imports-loader line to `loader: "imports-loader?$=jquery,_ol=ol,_control=ol/control,ol=>{inherits:_ol.inherits,control:_control}"`.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit and now it works for this one.   
`loader: "imports-loader?$=jquery,_ol=ol,_control=ol/control,ol=>{inherits:_ol.default.inherits%2Ccontrol:_control}"`

Comment: But now I get the problem with control.Control not being defined.

Comment: The ol.control was the issue. I forked the code and removed this in my version. Now I have included it